# Partial cancellation of a train ticket

Tags: trains

I have booked four person ticket of 3rd ac in one PNR number. Now I want to cancel two person ticket from them. Are the remaining two person tickets on same reservation valid or not?

Comment: Where, and which company?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking due to lack of information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can cancel tickets of passengers individually.

> Login to your [IRCTC](https://www.irctc.co.in) account  select booked history  select the
>   appropriate ticket then you can select check boxes side to the name of
>   passengers and select Cancel ticket this thing only cancels particular
>   ticket of that passengers and remaining tickets will be alive.

Hope this helps.
If you face trouble in this process provide your IRCTC login details I will do that for you.
 you can also find the process to perform this [here](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090901232030AAMZGAq) and [here](http://www.indiamike.com/india/indian-railways-f10/how-to-cancel-2-tickets-out-of-4-tickets-from-irctc-website-t128263/)

Comment: @HenningMakholm “PNR number” in the question implies India.

Comment: Amtrak in the US also knows PNRs if booked via Sabre (according to Google results). In combination with "3rd ac", it may be clear to people who are used to the Indian rail system that India is meant, though. It is certainly not good style by the OP not to even state these assumptions.

Comment: @HenningMakholm he mentioned India in his tags and I answered according to that it doesn't an assumption.

Comment: I really cannot understand why I got minus voting for this answer i am expecting some explanation from the one who casted negative vote I love to listen the reason

Comment: @HenningMakholm ok whatever 3rd AC and PNR related to Indian railways and OP is from India (his name derives that)so I answered related to Indian Railways.

Comment: @HenningMakholm why you are so concerned why did you remove that tag??I have said you 3 things why this post belong to India still you are in your way.

Comment: @dh47: The OP's question should not be arbitrarily restricted to be about a single railway when he didn't specify any such question himself. If he had said in a comment which railway he's asking about it would be appropriate to edit it into the question for him, but such a narrowing of the question **based on pure guesswork** is deeply inappropriate. It should be up to the OP to decide what he wants to ask about, not up to you and Gilles to decide that with his name he's only allowed to get answers about the railway you happen to know something about!

Comment: It's not pure guesswork, it's educated guesswork.  If he wants information on a specific railway operator or information more generally he can edit his question and provide that.  If you're truly concerned you can provide a more general answer, and he can accept the answer that most fits his needs.  As it is, if someone's trying to provide a  useful answer (IMO good on dh47 for attempting to do so) they have to fill in those gaps themselves.